# Google Docs Scripts:How to copy a list from one document and replace a list in another document with it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am writing a script for Google Docs to automatically combine Christmas wish lists from multiple documents into one document, and also to import them into separate planning documents. I have a script attached to a simple dropdown menu to run it, and in theory it should copy a wish list from one document, and replace a placeholder in another document, and then subsequently update that list. I am relatively new to Google Docs Scripts; I'm much more familiar with Sheets, but I am willing to embrace a workaround solution if that is necessary.

The main idea is to take a list like this:

[image: Wish List]

and use it to replace something like this:

[image: Place to Copy it]

Is such a thing possible, and if so, how would one go about it?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You wrote that you have a script. Can you share that and explain how it isn't meeting the acceptance criteria?

Comment: It is possible, but it would be easier to combine lists from different spreadsheets rather than Docs. If you provide a sample document and your existing script, I can look at it so see why it is not working.